# How to drive noise textures position with attributes?

Tags: shaders, smoke-simulation, fire, vector-mapping, mantaflow

I'm working on a fire simulation and I've been using a noise texture to remove parts of the fire.
[image]

So far I've just animated the Z value of the mapping to move the noise up. But I saw someone use an attribute node with "velocity" to drive the movement of the noise texture so it flowed exactly with the simulation. When I tried to replicate the technique I couldn't get it to work and the noise wouldn't appear at all.
[image: Viewing noise texture]

Am I doing this wrong? Is Mantaflow broken? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?